# Calling jspm minification from Gulp using gulp-jspm

Tags: gulp, minify, bundling-and-minification, jspm

I am working on a project which uses gulp to call jspm to minify all javascript files.

Gulp task supposed to be run is

```
    gulp.task('jspm_minify', function () {
       gulp.src('./app/spa/app.js')
         .pipe(gulp_jspm ())
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/js/'));
});
```

this gives following error,

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Unable to calculate canonical name to bundle C://\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\app\spa\app.js
    at getCanonicalNamePlain (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\utils.js:177:13)
    at getCanonicalName (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\utils.js:88:19)
    at C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\arithmetic.js:84:38
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:9)
From previous event:
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:371:17)
From previous event:
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\gulp-jspm\index.js:40:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:160:12)
    at doWrite (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:326:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:312:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:239:11)
    at write (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:664:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at emitReadable_ (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:448:10)
    at emitReadable (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:444:5)
    at readableAddChunk (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:187:9)
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:149:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:145:32)
    at afterTransform (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:101:12)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:79:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.noop [as _transform] (C:\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\through2.js:26:3)
```

But if i run the minification using normal command line code below, it works.

```
jspm bundle app/spa/app  wwwroot/js/spa.min.js --minify
```

Our application is a SPA. Uses angular JS. Uses JSPM to load and manage modules.

Any one came across this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a slash problem

In your first line of error log:

```
C://\code\Dev-Stable\src\ProjectName.Web\app\spa\app.js
```

Maybe you can use [gulp-slash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-slash) or change the path by yourself.